# How to know total size of data?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming, libevent

I'm using libevent for creating a small p2p network.

Let's say that I want to send 10,000 bytes buffer from one node to another, due to libevent the max size that can be send in one time is 4,096 bytes (so 4,096 + 4,096 + 1,808).

Is it technically possible (in TCP protocol) for the node that receives the data, to know the total number of bytes that will be sent when receives the first 4,096 bytes ?

Comment: Nope, recipient will not know the length of data to expect or even multiple data. TCP guarantees, flow order, so you need to tell the recipient in first few bytes `how much more is yet to come`. [TLV Buffers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value)

Comment: Lukkyz Is the "send 10,000 bytes buffer", binary data, text, what?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It is text.

Comment: Even after you send all 10000 bytes the receiver doesn't know that you sent 10000 bytes

Answer (score 0):

No.  It is, however, common for the application protocol to tell the receiver how many bytes to expect.  With HTTP 1.1, it's the `Content-Length` header.  You can also use length prefix along the lines of `<len><data>`.  [PostgresSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/protocol-message-formats.html) uses that protocol between the front and backend.